# Resizing the Button of ReactBootstrap in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, react-bootstrap

I am struggling to stretch the `buynow` button to the length of the paper box(@material-ui) above, the `buynow button` using the react-bootstrap,i have seen the `raectbootstrap` site but couldnt find any usefull info of change the size of the button, any suggestions please

[image: Photo showing the button that need extended till the boarder of top Paper component]

-`Snippet` of code below

```
 <div style={{ float: "right", paddingRight: "5rem" }}>
        <TableContainer
          className="basket-summary"
          component={Paper}
          style={{ float: "right", top: "0", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", maxHeight: "9vw", maxWidth: "14vw" }}
        >
          <Table >
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Summary </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              <tr>
                <td>SubTotal:{totalPrice}</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
        <ButtonGroup aria-label="quantityofproduct">
          <Button className=" button-block" variant="primary" name="subtract" value="subtract" onClick={() => buyNow(basketItems)}>
            Buy Now
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
      </div>
```

-`CSS` formatting

```
.basket-summary {
    min-height: 15rem;
  min-width: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button just needs to have a `min-width: 100%`, which makes it fill the parent width.

```
.button-block {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```